# How to check there is only one object inside the ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby variable @object which can have only one object inside it or multiple objects.
How to check that in Rails.
Tried checking with

```
.length
.size
.count
```

Comment: What's the type of your `@object` variable?

Comment: It can have any object/objects of a class, a variable, or array

Comment: Is it rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: ruby 2.2.1, rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael's answer should work already, but another option is to check if it includes the `Enumerable` module (should support all "Array"-ish objects, unless they have their own custom implementation):

```
@object.is_a? Enumerable
# => returns true if Array-ish or false
```

### Examples

```
# Array
[].is_a? Enumerable
# => true

# Hash
{}.is_a? Enumerable
# => true

# Set
[].to_set.is_a? Enumerable
# => true

# Subclass of any of the above
class MyArr < Array
end
MyArr.new.is_a? Enumerable
# => true

# ActiveRecord::Relation
User.all.is_a? Enumerable
# => true

# String
'somestring'.is_a? Enumerable
# => false

# Integer/Float
123.is_a? Enumerable
# => false
(123.45).is_a? Enumerable
# => false

# Time
Time.now.is_a? Enumerable
# => false
```

### Gotcha

```
## Rails 4:
ActionController::Parameters.new.is_a? Enumerable
# => true

## Rails 5:
ActionController::Parameters.new.is_a? Enumerable
# => false
# in Rails 5, ActionController::Parameters no longer inherits from Hash

# ActionController::Parameters is the type of the variable `params` in your controllers
# Because practically speaking you can loop over it, so it should still be an "Array"
# Therefore, you might want to use the following instead of `.is_a? Enumerable`
@object.respond_to? :each
# => returns true if Array-ish or false

ActionController::Parameters.new.respond_to? :each
# => true
```

Comment: This is the case when you know the variable type either hash or array. But what happen if the variable have an object/objects.

Comment: What do you mean "variable have an object/objects"? Can you provide an example? Everything in ruby is an object. Were you referring to "variable have belongs_to / has_many associations" instead?

Comment: Or if you were not talking about model relationships (like belongs_to / has_many), then were you talking about "variable have instance_variable objects" instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `respond_to?` method

```
@object.respond_to? :size
```

It returns true if array of objects

Comment: Many things respond to `.size`. Strings, for example.

Comment: yep, `count` be better

Comment: Strings respond to that too.